# How to position an ImageView on top of a LinearLayout with %?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, position

I'm trying to create something like this in android:

[image]

My current approach is to try to create the bar with a linearLayout and some views with different weights. This works just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/market_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But now how can I add the markers that appear in the image? I don't think I can achieve this with weights. For example, how to position the marker at the end of the bar?

Thank you

Comment: use farmelayout as your base your layout .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a LinearLayout with a FrameLayout to improve the code. 
This is the Graphical layout:

[image: Graphical layout]

And this is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:text="Actual" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/market_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/actual"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/apertura"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/market_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="120dp"
        android:text="Apertura" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I recommend you also to check this link: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get if you want to build a static view or something that is like an interactive double slider.
By the way, considering the first case, you can move the markers by tuning the `android:layout_marginLeft`.

An example based on your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/market_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```